# Block Cypher Code

Tags: c++, arrays, string, encryption, multidimensional-array

I have been tasked to write a program which reads the standard input, stores text until it encounters EOF, then encrypts the text using the Caesar Block Cipher.

STEPS TO A SOLUTION:

1. So: read your message into a large buffer or a string object.
2. Either remove the spaces and punctuation or not
3. Then count the chars in the message.
4. Pick the first perfect square greater than the message length,
   allocate an array of char that size.
5. Read the message into a square
   array of that size from left to right, top to bottom.
6. Write the message out top to bottom, left to right, and you've enciphered it.

This is what I have so far... It compiles but doesn't do anything.  I know I must be missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // read in char from keyboard
    string buff;
    do
    {
        cin >> buff;
    } while ( ! cin.eof()) ;

    // delete spaces and punctuation
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof ( buff ) ; i++ )
    {
        if  ( !isalnum ( buff[i] )  )
        {
            buff.erase( i,1 );
            --i;
        }
    }

    // get length of edited string
    int static SIZE = buff.length(); //strlen (buff);

    // pick first perfect _square_ greater then the message length (ex:7x7)
    int  squared = static_cast <int> ( sqrt( static_cast <double> ( SIZE )) + .5f );

    // allocate an array of char that size
    char ** board;
    board = new char *[squared];      // array of 'squared' char pointers
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < squared ; i++ )
        board[i] = new char[squared];

    // read messsage into a square array of that size from left to right top to bottom
    for ( int c = 0 ; c < squared  ; c++ )
        for ( int r = 0 ; r < squared ; r++ )
            buff[r] = board[r][c];

    // write the message out top to bottom, left to right and its been encyphered
    for ( int r = 0 ; r < squared  ; r++ )
        for ( int c = 0 ; c < squared ; c++ )
            cout << board[r][c] << endl;

    // delete array
    delete [] board;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < squared ; ++i )
        delete [] board[i] ;

} // end main
```

Comment: The order of your closing `delete[]` logic is going to make things rather... interesting... during shutdown.

Comment: haha thanks @WhozCraig. I switched that around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried compiling your code and running it - found a number of problems.

1) Your "erase" loop goes into an infinite loop. It is usually very bad practice to start at the beginning of an array, loop through all elements, delete elements while you go through, and expect things to be right at the end. It is much safer to start at the end and work backwards:

```
for(ii = buff.length() - 1; ii>=0; ii--) {
  if  ( !isalnum ( buff[i] )  )
    {
    cout << "erasing " << buff[i] << endl;
    buff.erase( i,1 );
    }
  }
}
```

You do

```
delete [] board;
```

before deleting the individual elements in the array... Not sure what the syntax there is, but it doesn't look right to me!

Your board is not big enough. You have to use the `ceil` function to make sure you really get the "next biggest" number:

```
square = ceil(sqrt(buff.length()));
```

And the big blooper: you copy the (empty) buffer into your input string instead of the other way around:

```
buff[r] = board[r][c];
```

Which should be

```
ii = 0;
for(( int c = 0 ; c < squared  ; c++ )
  for ( int r = 0 ; r < squared ; r++ )
    board[r][c] = buff[ii++];
```

There may be others... still working out the kinks.

EDIT: Here is complete, working code.

```
    // read in char from keyboard
    int i;
    string buff;
    cout << "enter the text to be encoded" << endl;
    getline(cin,buff);
    cout << "done reading in the text!" << endl;
    cout << "buffer size is " << buff.length() << endl;
    cout << "the string is " << endl << buff << endl;
    // delete spaces and punctuation
    for ( i = buff.length()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--)
        {
            if  ( !isalnum ( buff[i] )  )
           {
           buff.erase( i,1 );
            }
        }

// get length of edited string
 int static SIZE = buff.length(); //strlen (buff);
cout << "the string length is " << SIZE << endl;

 // pick first perfect _square_ greater then the message length (ex:7x7)
int  squared = static_cast <int> ( ceil(sqrt( static_cast <double> ( SIZE ))));
cout << "size of board is " << squared << endl;
// allocate an array of char that size
char ** board;
board = new char *[squared];      // array of 'squared' char pointers
for ( i = 0 ; i < squared ; i++ )
    board[i] = new char[squared];

// read messsage into a square array of that size from left to right top to bottom
i = 0;
for ( int c = 0 ; c < squared  ; c++ )
    for ( int r = 0 ; r < squared ; r++ )
       board[r][c] = toupper(buff[i++]);

  // write the message out top to bottom, left to right and its been encyphered
 for ( int r = 0 ; r < squared  ; r++ ){
    for ( int c = 0 ; c < squared ; c++ ){
        cout << board[r][c];}
    cout << endl;
    }

   // delete array
    for ( i = 0 ; i < squared ; ++i )
     delete [] board[i] ;

    delete [] board;
} // end main
```

Note I changed the input method to get a complete sentence, not just one word; I convert all characters to upper case (very Roman - it means there are no hints about characters at start of sentence, names, etc), added a carriage retiurn only at the end of a complete line of output (instead of every line), as well as the problems identified earlier.

Happy encrypting!
Oh - one afterthought. You will want to get rid of the carriage returns in the output once you confirm that things look good (easy to do by reading the text in columns). It should of course appear as a single line of text without these breaks!

Comment: Thanks so much! That's great advice.  Note, I switched the order of my delete array already, but I'm sure you'll catch that in the code as well.

Comment: You are welcome. You can express your thanks by "accepting" the answer... (click the little check mark by the answer that best solved your question).

Answer (score 0):

This is odd

```
string buff;
do
{
    cin >> buff;
} while ( ! cin.eof());
```

Not sure what you think that will achieve. Why not just this?

```
string buff;
cin >> buff;
```

Another error

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof ( buff ) ; i++ )
```

should be

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < buff.length() ; i++ )
```

You got this right a couple of lines later, so not sure why it's wrong here.

Comment: Thanks John, good catch! I was attempting to make it a "water-pump" type of code where you can continue to enter chars until EOF and do this again and again.

Comment: @user2255496, ok but then your **whole program** has to be inside the do while loop, not just the input statement.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Now I've edited it w/ & w/o the while loop at the beginning and it will compile w/o errors but crashes after I type any text and hit enter. What could be causing this?